# DFA transtion table

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I have the following DFA transition table for the regular expression ab.

[image]

I don't understand these hyphens.As we know DFA is a deterministic automata and each state is defined for both a and b. However, if we look at state 1, we know that if 'b' comes we will move to state 2 but while standing on state 1 if 'a' then to which state we will move?

Comment: This isn't a DFA.

Comment: @RoiDivon I found this example over here: http://regex-automaton.com/transition_table.php

Comment: in DFAs, for every state and every input there is a next state (given by the transition table). This isn't the case here. This might be a NFA (non-deterministic finite automata)